# Java - accumulator variable not incrementing after each loop iteration

Tags: java, loops, output

When a car departs, the number of times a car was moved inside the garage should be shown along with the car plate. The output I am currently getting shows everything just fine, but the number of moves remains at 0 for all cars. I am having trouble figuring how to increment the variable and show the accumulated value in the output. How can I fix it?

Car class

```
package garagetester;

public class Car 
{
    private String licensePlate;//stores the license plate of the car as a String
    private int movesCount = 0;//stores the number of times the car has been 
                           //moved 


    public Car(String licensePlate)//builds a Car object with 
    {
       this.licensePlate = licensePlate;
    } 


    public String getLicensePlate() {
        return licensePlate;
    }


    public int getMovesCount() {
        return movesCount;
    }


    public void incrementMovesCount(int movesCount) {
        movesCount++;
     }
}//end of Car class
```

Garage Class

```
package garagetester;


public class Garage {

private Car[] garage; //array, stores Car objects 
private final int LIMIT = 10; //determines length of the garage array 
private int count;//number of cars in garage 

public Garage() {
    garage = new Car[LIMIT];
    //creates an array of 10 elements 
    //first index = 0, last index = 9

public String arrive(Car newCar) {
    String str = ""; //stores the result of the ARRIVE operation            
    /* If the garage is empty, the first car to arrive is parked in 
            the first empty spot closest to the exit*/ 
    if (count != LIMIT) {
        garage[count] = newCar;
        count++;
        str = newCar.getLicensePlate() + " has been parked";
    } else {
        str = "Sorry, " + newCar.getLicensePlate() + " the garage is full.";
    }
    return str;
}//end of arrive()

public String depart(String plate) {
    String str = ""; //stores the result of executing the operation 
    int moves =0; //stores the number of times a car has been moved 
    boolean found = false; //flag 
    for (int i = 0; i < count - 1; i++) //for all elements in the array
    {
        //check if car with that plate number is in the garage 
        if (plate.equals(garage[i].getLicensePlate())) 
        {
            found = true; //car has been found 
            if (found)//if found=true 
            {
                //for all cars ahead of it 
                for (int j = i + 1; j < count; j++)//check if count or count-1
                {   
                    moves += garage[j].getMovesCount();
                    garage[j].incrementMovesCount(moves);
                }
                //for all cars behind it 
                for (int k = i; k > 0; k--) //or k=i-1, check when debugging 
                {
                    //move all cars behind it one position up
                    garage[k] = garage[k - 1];
                }
                str = plate + " has departed." + "it has been moved " + moves 
                        + " times. "; 
                count--; //decrease the number of cars in the garage by 1 
            }
            else 
                {
                    str = "Sorry " + plate + " is not in the garage.";
                }
            }
        }//end of for loop 
        return str;//prints the value stored in str            
    } //end of depart() 
} //end of Garage class
```

Garage Tester Class

```
package garagetester;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GarageTester 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException 
    {
       //Initializes an array of 10 Car objects 
       Garage newGarage = new Garage();

       //initializes a Scanner object to read data from file 
       Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("garage.txt"));

       //while there is tokens in the file 
       while (scan.hasNext()) 
       {
          String plate = scan.next();//stores the plate number read from file
          String action = scan.next();//stores the action read from file

           //evaluate action 
            switch (action) {
            //if action has the value "ARRIVE"
                case "ARRIVE": 
                    Car aCar = new Car(plate);//create a Car object
                    System.out.println(newGarage.arrive(aCar));//call arrive method
                    break;
                //if action has the value "DEPART"
                case "DEPART":
                    System.out.println(newGarage.depart(plate));//call the depart method 
                    break;
            } //end of switch case
        }//end of while
    }//end of main()
} //end of GarageTester class
```

Comment: You should initialize the count variable in your constructor I would think

Comment: In `incrementMovesCount` you have a parameter with the same name as the class member. That parameter is unneeded so you can delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your increment method should be like this in `Car.java`;

```
public void incrementMovesCount() {
    this.movesCount++;
 }
```

Also fix the other usage of this method. There is no need to send any data to new value. Car object has a `movesCount` field. That means , it can increment the `movesCount` itself.

If you dont want to change method signature , use this;

```
public void incrementMovesCount(int newMovesCount) {
    this.movesCount = newMovesCount;  //--newMovesCount refers to your calculation
 }
```

but be carefull when using the last solution, because you are sending param as ;

```
moves += garage[j].getMovesCount();  //this moves never set to 0. Just equal to zero in the first iteration.
garage[j].incrementMovesCount(moves);
```

This is wrong i think. Because i suppose you wants to increment all of car's position. If you wants to apply first solution of my post, just fix compile error. But if you wants to apply second solution, just change this part like ;

```
garage[j].incrementMovesCount(garage[j].getMovesCount()+1);
```

Comment: @LiliaCurbeloJalil I would change this answer to the accepted answer, since this answer's author provides a more thorough solution than my own.

Comment: @JonnyHenly Just did it. Thank you, I'm still working out the kinks :)

Answer (score 1):

Your parameter `movesCount` is shadowing the class member `movesCount`. In the following mutator:

```
public void incrementMovesCount(int movesCount) {
    // movesCount++; --> this is incrementing the parameter

    // either remove the parameter `movesCount` from this mutator
    // since it's not being used, or do the following
    this.movesCount++; // --> this refers to the class member movesCount
}
```